# Run Eclipse Project x times until a thrown error occurs

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a java project which does not output the same result every time it is ran and object variables are changed upon each call of the starting method in main, resulting in a case where an errors are not thrown for some runs of the program, but sometimes an error may pop up in a niche case. This has led me to running the program over and over until some exception *may* be thrown.

Is there a way in Eclipse to run main over and over x amount of times until it encounters (or doesnt!) a caught error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try catch keywords.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    // do something
    }
    // exits system if encounters any exception
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

If you wish to run the main method a specific number of times, you can put all your method inside the try statement and then inside a for loop. If you are looking for a specific exception, you can change the word "Exception" to your desired exception. For example:

```
try {
        // do something
    }
    // exits system if encounters any exception
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

You can put as many catch statements as you would like for each of the desired exceptions

Comment: I know about catching exceptions, I have try-catch blocks everywhere in my code. My question is whether I can run code from new alot of times until eclipse finds an error being caught. I cannot put the try catch inside a loop as the state of my program changes as it is run, hence potentially missing an error in a previous state.